# Is there an industry standard to have the text of a button in capital or small letters for Android?

Tags: android, textview

This may be a mundane question but I wanted to confirm if displaying the text of a button in capitals (like 'OK' or 'REGISTER') is acceptable or should it be in regular text (like 'Ok' or 'Register').

Thanks in advance.

P.S

I don't want to be seeminlgly shout at people using caps in buttons :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Android Design site, you can see some examples of text under [Writing Style](http://developer.android.com/design/style/writing.html) which have just the first letter capitalized. "OK" is a bit of a special case though as it's an abbreviation of sorts, so I'd leave that with both letters capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

The Android design guide details that and a lot more in the [writing style page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/writing.html). Do not use all caps...

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard, at least for buttons and labels it seems to be more of a "design choice". In ICS some of the text (e.g. preference and tab labels) are shown all in CAPS. Interestingly enough, there's a setting for textviews to accomplish that: `android:textAllCaps`. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextAllCaps). If it's a block of text of course, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use the Java String function toUpperCase() or toLowerCase()

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I misunderstood the question.